# data not show ajax and javascript ci

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to use **ajax , javascript snd CI** php select option cat_id  click after show relataed sub-cat-id but not show data . i am testin alert data show fine but making html data not geting please share valuable idea sir share code here..

**ajax javascript**

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#catid').on('click', function() {
           var catid = $("#catid").val();

           $.ajax({
               url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>get-form-detail",
               type: "post",
               data: "catid=" + catid,
                success: function(response) {
                   var res = JSON.parse(response);
                   
                  for(i=0;i<res.length;i++)
                            {
                                
                                //alert(res[i]['cat_title']);
                                
                                options +=  '<option value="' + res[i]['id'] + '">' + res[i]['cat_title'] + '</option>';
                                $('#tbl').html(options); 
                            }
                    
                 
               }
           });
       });
   });  
   </script>
```

**view page**

```
<div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-right">Form Category : </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                           <div class="form-group">
                              <select class="form-control" name="formID" id="formID">
                                <div id="tbl"></div> 
                              </select>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change callback function to

```
success: function(response) {
    let res = JSON.parse(response);
    let options = res.reduce((a,v)=>(`${a}<option value = "${v['id']}">${v['cat_title']}</option>`), '');
    $('#formID').html(options);                 
}
```

And use this html code

```
<select class="form-control" name="formID" id="formID"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

idk how u to add more item using variable  option but i have another solution

**Replace your code :**

```
   var x = document.getElementById("yourSelectElementId");

   for(i=0;i<res.length;i++){
                                
        var option = document.createElement("option");

        option.text = res[i]['id'];
        option.value= res[i]['id'];

        x.add(option);
                              
    }
```